# PHP syntax for if / elseif / else but for 4 conditions

Tags: php, if-statement

I need to implement 3 'if conditions' in my script, i've looked it up online but I can only find solutions up to 2 if's like below

```
<?
if (condition 1){
    do something;
}
elseif (condition 2){
    do something else;
}
else {
    do this last;
}
?>
```

but I would need something like this:

```
if (condition 1) { do this };
else if (condition 2) {do that}; 
or else if (condition 3) {do that};
else (do this)
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: checkout switch statements.

Comment: Your code will work as written if you remove the word `or`

Comment: Remove the `or` and it's valid. You can add as much `else if` as you want.

Comment: I did try with 2x elseif but it's not working that way... I'm using Kohana Framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply

```
if(condition){

}
else if(condition){

}
else if(condition){

}
else{

}
```

you can use switch case statements too. you can use else if as many as you want. Each condition inside if() can accept **OR** and **AND** operators as || for OR and && for AND you can use.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (condition 1) { do this 
} else if (condition 2) {do that
} else if (condition 3) {do that
} else { do this }
```

alternatively if you want to check one variable each time you can use a `switch` for example

```
$myvar = 5;

switch($myvar){
    case 1:
        //do this
        break;
    case 2: 
        //do that
        break;
    case 3: 
        //do that
        break;
    default:
        //do this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this construction

```
if ( $a == $b ) {
    // something...
} else if ( $a == $c ) {
    // something...
} else if ( $a == $d ) {
    // something...
} else {
    // otherwise...
}
```

But if all of the conditions are ( $a equals to something ) it's better to use switch ... case:

```
switch ( $a ) {
    case $b:
        // something...
        break;
    case $c:
        // something...
        break;
    case $d:
        // something...
        break;
    default:
        // otherwise...
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

Using many `elseif` statements as you want.

Use this solution when your conditions are complex, or comparing different variables.

```
if (/*condition 1*/) {
  // Action to condition 1
} else if (/*condition 2*/) {
  // Action to condition 2
} else if (/*condition 3*/) {
  // Action to condition 3
} else if (/*condition n*/) {
  // Action to condition n
} else {
  // Action when no conditions match.
}
```

## Solution 2

Using `switch` statement:

Use this condition when you want to compare a variable against constant values:

```
switch ($age) {
    case 0:
        return 'You are a baby';
        break;
    case 18:
        return 'You are 18 years old';
        break;
    case 21:
    case 22:
    case 23:
        return 'You are too old';
    default:
        return 'Unexpected age :(';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the or operator, `||`:

```
if (condition 1) { do this }
else if (condition 2 || condition 3) {do that}
else {do this}
```

An example:

```
<?php

function testCondition($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        print ("They are the same<br />\n");
    }
    else if ($a == "a" || $b == "b") {
        print ("One is the same as its letter<br />\n");
    }
    else {
        print ("They are some other sort<br />\n");
    }
}

testCondition("c","c");
testCondition("a","c");
testCondition("a","b");
testCondition("d","e");

?>
```

Outputs:

```
They are the same
One is the same as its letter
One is the same as its letter
They are some other sort
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as first stated here. I have four variables but the second one is skipped and only 1,3, and 4 work. Why?

```
if(empty($fromName) or empty($fromEmail) or empty($subject) or empty($comments)) {
    echo 'You cannot submit the form with empty fields. Please correct the form and resubmit.';
    return false;
}
elseif($fieldDelete == "Delete this text!"){    
         echo "Delete the contents of the fourth field before submitting.";
         return false;
}
elseif  (($fromName == "Curtisvien") || ($fromName == "Thomastymn") || ($fromName == "RichardMark")) {
        echo "Failed. Please try again.";
        return false;   
}

else {
        $flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers");
        $imgfile = "images/NatMap logo2.gif";
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $imgbinary = fread(fopen($imgfile, "r"), filesize($imgfile));   
        echo '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary) . '" width=427 height=72 />';
        echo "\n<br />\n<br />Thank You!  An e-mail has been sent to the National Map web team and they will get back to you in the next 24-48 hours.";
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: have you tried to invert statements 2 and 3 to make sure it's not your conditions that's causing it to be skipped? elseif ($fromName ...) first then elseif ($fieldDelete...) this way you'll find out if it's a issue related to your if/elseif statements or not...

Comment: The 2nd condition is broken whether it is 2nd or 3rd. Any suggestions?